# How do I change alignment of a button in java?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

So, i want to make an adding activity which is used for 3 different tables.
In the last one i want the date EditText to be gone.

I know how to make it disappear but i want the layout o change too and this is how it looks when date EditText is present

[3 EditTexts and Button with alignbottom set to date EditText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjrqc.png)

And this is how it looks when I set date EditText to gone

[2 EditTexts and Button with alignbottom set to the gone EditText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k0yi.png)

Comment: What is your expected layout then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`LinearLayout` with orientation of vertical containing the EditText, wrapped in a horizontal `LinearLayout` containing the `Button` too. If both the `LinearLayout` and the `Button` have a height of wrap content, they will adapt regardless of how many `EditText` there are

[image]

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#3e3e3e" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ty, same answer as Matcoil told me, but i have the main items in a RelativeLayout, because i have a spinner set to gone, so i can't use horizontal LinearLayout

Comment: The key is in the weights? it is not, at all!

Answer (score 1):

Try layout like that:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="visible"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The thing is, that you need another supporting layout, which is the number two in my hierarchy, which will have android:layout_height="wrap_content", so when you set the visibility to gone to one of the EditTexts, it is gonna change the height of the LinearLayout according to the other two EditTexts height, where Button's height is always android:layout_height="match_parent".

Comment: tried, and the button will be too long, like the date EditText was still there

Comment: alright, I thought, thats what you want. so you want the button to be the height of the remaining two edittexts?

Comment: ty, i've rewritten the code to align button tot the linear layout where the EditTexts are